# Pass variable in a URL

Tags: programming, arduino-yun, variables

I am working on code where I am able to manually enter the value in the URL to let the PHP code save it in the database, but I'm unsure how to do it with a variable in a loop running. This is the URL:

```
student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=25
```

Code:

```
void setup() {
  // Initialize Bridge
  Bridge.begin();

  // Initialize Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Wait until a Serial Monitor is connected.
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("Ready");

  // run various example processes

}

void loop() {
   runCurl();
   delay(10000);
}

void runCurl() {
  // Launch "curl" command and get Arduino ascii art logo from the network
  // curl is command line program for transferring data using different internet protocols
  Process p;        // Create a process and call it "p"
  p.begin("curl");  // Process that launch the "curl" command
  p.addParameter("student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=25"); // Add the URL parameter to "curl"
  p.run();      // Run the process and wait for its termination

  // A process output can be read with the stream methods
  while (p.available()>0) {
    char c = p.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  // Ensure the last bit of data is sent.
  Serial.flush();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "manually entering" do you want to do subsequent curls as: verdi=25, verdi=26...?

Comment: If that's the case take a look to [string appender](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAppendOperator)

Comment: yes! hthwen. I want to do it in a loop so you can put a variable in verdi=$variable

Comment: Please note that duplicates (or close variants) of this question were also cross-posted to Stack Overflow and EE.SE. Cross-posting is against Stack Exchange policy, so they have been migrated/merged where possible. Some variations in question information have been lost in this process.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in a variable into a function. Something like this:

```
void runCurl(int verdi) {
    ...
    String myUrl = "student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=";
    myUrl += verdi;
    p.addParameter(myUrl);
    ...
}
```

You call the function like this, now:

```
runCurl(1);
runCurl(2);
runCurl(someVar);
```

and so on. Since it's already in your main `loop()` function, you just need to set pass in a different number based on whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: String myUrl = "student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=" + verdi;

is wrong, you can't concatenate array of char (pointer to char) to a int, you'll get erratic result.
you need to do concatenation: solution 1:
String myUrl = "student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=";
myUrl += verdi;
that mean: string(array of char) is casted to String(object) and then verdi is concatenated to the String objcet; or
String myUrl = String("student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=") + String(verdi);

Comment: @lesto you're right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you declare your `buffer` as a string of 50 characters, but

```
student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=
```

is already 48, and you start your value at 1200 and increments over that, so basically

```
sprintf (buffer, "student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=%d", val)
```

will create a buffer of 53 characters (52 characters + `\0`).

Secondly, it's always a better idea to give the *full* URL to a program such as curl, as it might work but may give unexpected results as well if you do not provide the protocol… `curl` could legally assume you want `ftp` or `gopher` to access that address!

```
http://student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=%d
```

Third, here's how you setup and use your `val` variable:

```
int val=1200;
sprintf (…, "…", val);  
val++;
```

so once you've reached `32767` your int is overflowing, getting back to `-32,768`.

Oh, and by the way, it is good practice on a Q&A site such as Stack Overflow to actually *ask* a question and say what your problem is. All my hints here are insights based on reading your flawed code.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I'm assuming you mean that you need the last part of the url varied from, say 1 to 100. Like Java, Processing, and, by extension, Arduino, allow you to add an integer to a String to get a String. I haven't tested this out, but it should work:

```
#include <Process.h>
#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100

int i;

void setup() {
  i = MIN;

  // Initialize Bridge
  Bridge.begin();

  // Initialize Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Wait until a Serial Monitor is connected.
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("Ready");

  // run various example processes

}

void loop() {
   if (i<=MAX) {
     runCurl();  
     i = i+1; 
   }
   delay(10000);
}

void runCurl() {
  // Launch "curl" command and get Arduino ascii art logo from the network
  // curl is command line program for transferring data using different internet protocols
  Process p;        // Create a process and call it "p"
  p.begin("curl");  // Process that launch the "curl" command
  String myUrl = "student.cs.hioa.no/~s180343/updatedb.php?verdi=";
  p.addParameter(myUrl+i); // Add the URL parameter to "curl"
  p.run();      // Run the process and wait for its termination

  // A process output can be read with the stream methods
  while (p.available()>0) {
    char c = p.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  // Ensure the last bit of data is sent.
  Serial.flush();
}
```